# Deployment of C# console application for Keyboard Listener

Tags: c#, console, listener, keypress

I have a C# console application that is designed to run in the background and capture key press events and if it matches my hotkey I want to do some action and NOT pass that key on to the active application.

On my development machine I can run the build exe file without visual studio and my program works as expected. When I type my hotkey, (f11 or f12), anywhere, in any application, that key event is captured and not passed on to the active application. When I deploy the exe to another machine, same OS, (Windows 8.1 Pro), the key press is detected and I can "do something", (see code), but then it is passed on to the active application. This is not the desired operation nor what I am experiencing on my development machine. My specific question, is there something else I need to do in order to deploy this application to other machines so that they key press event is not only captured but ALSO not passed on to the active application?

```
    public delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    public static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            Keys pressedKey = (Keys)Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            if (pressedKey == Keys.F11 || pressedKey == Keys.F12)
            {
                // Do something...

                // Don't pass the key press on to the system
                return (System.IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
```

Comment: Do not make people click links to your code, and do not post that much code in a question. Please try to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that in your question.

Comment: I have updated my question per your useful input. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: That is a much better question, and it will likely be re-opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting lParam to null?  It's been a while since i've done key handling, so not sure if it's better to set to null or IntPtr.Zero. One of the two should work:

```
public static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        Keys pressedKey = (Keys)Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

        if (pressedKey == Keys.F11 || pressedKey == Keys.F12)
        {
            // Do something...

            // Don't pass the key press on to the system
            lParam = null;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: That was all it was. Thank you for the answer! I was banging my head on this for some time. Sorry I didn't get to it in time to award you the bounty.

Answer (score 5):

There are a large number of niggly problems in [your code](http://codepad.org/aFrhM98y), all of which conspire to have no idea why it doesn't run on another machine.  Going through the source:

```
    static bool debug = false;
```

You don't stand a chance to diagnose anything with that variable set to false.  You catch exceptions and don't display the exception message and stack trace.  You are blind as a bat.  This should be a configuration item.

```
    static string _com = "COM3";
```

*Never* hard-code serial port numbers.  The odds that it is still COM3 on another machine with another USB emulator and another driver are very low.  You have to make it a configuration item.

```
    setConsoleWindowVisibility(false);
```

You lost your only chance to see diagnostics.  This needs if (!debug) in front of it.

```
    _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
```

There is no error checking at all.  If SetWindowsHookEx() fails then you'll never know.  Pinvoking winapi functions *always* require error checking, you no longer have the friendly .NET exceptions to keep you out of trouble.  Throw a Win32Exception when a winapi call fails.

```
    scaleSerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
```

Serial port devices always use handshaking.  They pay attention to your DTR and RTS signals and won't send anything when they are off.  Easy to not see this when you debug your code, you'll use a terminal emulator program that turns these signals on.  Won't work on another machine.  You will have to set the DtrEnable and RtsEnable properties to *true* explicitly.

```
    if (scaleSerialPort.IsOpen)
        scaleSerialPort.Close();
    try
    {
        scaleSerialPort.Open();
        open = true;
    }
```

This is never correct, the MSDN article for SerialPort.Close() specifically warns about this.  SerialPort uses a worker thread to raise its events, the Close() method doesn't wait until that thread completes.  Trying to open it again immediately will always fail, the port is still opened by that worker thread.  Just never do this, open the port when your app start and don't close it until it ends.

```
    scaleSerialPort.ReadTimeout = 200;
```

Strongly avoid using timeouts that get close the amount of time your program can go catatonic because the machine gets busy or significant parts of your process gets paged out.  You should not use timeouts at all since you rely on DataReceived.  If you want to use them anyway then always make them 10 times bigger than the worst case.  Don't go below 5000.

```
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (debug) Console.WriteLine(e);
        Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to scale.");
        SendKeys.SendWait("^a");
        SendKeys.SendWait("Error-C23");
    }
```

Just never do this.  If you can't get the port opened then there is absolutely no point in keeping your program running.  Be sure to crash loudly, write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException to tell the tale.  *Never* poke keystrokes like that, you have no idea where they go.

```
    Double.TryParse(...);
```

The return value of this method is *not* optional.  Plowing along and ignoring the failed conversion just produces undiagnosable mis-behavior.

```
    return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
```

.NET 4.0 no longer emulates module handles for managed code.  You should be using LoadLibrary("user32") to get a valid handle.  Not a problem on Windows 8, it accepts a *null* value for the module handle, but a problem on earlier versions.

```
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
```

That's okay, but what if another keyboard hook intercepts the keystrokes first?  You'll lose of course.

```
    if (pressedKey == Keys.F11 || pressedKey == Keys.F12)
```

I'd strong recommend you do *not* use a low-level keyboard hook to just catch two keystrokes.  The much better mousetrap is RegisterHotKey().  You'll have no trouble googling sample code.  Automatically solves the "another app sees the keystrokes anyway" problem.

Well, it's probably one of those, I can't guess which :)  Good luck.

Comment: This is not my full code. I am connecting to very specific devices and `COM3` is default on most of them. I have a configuration option by pressing `F1` that allows setting changes to the serial port.  These serial devices do not use any handshake protocols. I will carefully review your comments though and adjust where it makes sense. I have done a lot of work with serial devices and never run into issues with some of the points brought up. I will update my question with results. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the solution you expect, but I'll post it anyway.

I use a different approach to capture this kind of events, Windows provides the possibility to register a "global hotkey" that will be intercepted anywhere, no matter if the target application is running or not (in fact it's hooked to the operating system, and not a single application).

You can try with this snippet https://gist.github.com/bruce965/87caacfb0289d0ad1b3c that can be called like this:

```
new HotkeyHandler(false, false, false, false, Keys.F11).Register(yourForm);
new HotkeyHandler(false, false, false, false, Keys.F12).Register(yourForm);
```

where `yourForm` is a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` with the following code:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    if(m.Msg == HotkeyHandler.WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID) {
        // Handle hotkey
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

You don't need for the form to be open or visible, just be sure it's running with:

```
Application.Run(yourForm);
```

---

From the linked snippet for quick reference:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

// make sure the second parameter '1234' is unique for every registered hotkey
RegisterHotKey(yourForm.Handle, 1234, 0, (int) Keys.F11);
```